# Firebase security rules for anonymous users

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to secure my cloud Firestore for a scenario where users can read and "claim" items without being authenticated.

In my flutter app users can put a bunch of items on one or many list and these lists can be published / shared. People with access to an item list (unique share link) can claim items on the list anonymously.

An item can be on multiple lists (some of which are shared) and a list contains multiple items, the DB structure looks like this:

```
users
  user1
    items
      item1
        name: "Item 1 name"
        listIds: [list1, list2]
      items2
        name: "Item 2 name"
        listIds: []
    lists
      list1
        name: "List 1 name"
        isShared: true
      list2
        name: "List 2 name"
        isShared: false
  user2
    ...

shared_lists
    list1
    ...
```

I want to give read access to items under /users/items but restrict access to items that are only on private lists or not on lists at all.

```
match /users/{uid}/items/{itemId}{
    
  //allow read: if ???;
  
  //delete, create only by owner
  allow create, delete: if request.auth.uid == uid;
  
  //update by owner or not claimed or same user
  allow update: if request.auth.uid == uid || !resource.data.isClaimed || resource.data.claimedbyUserId == request.auth.uid; 
  
}
```

My code for getting all wishes on a shared list looks like this:

```
fb.usersCollection.doc(share.userId).collection('items').where("listIds", "array-contains", share.listId).onSnapshot(snapshot => {...}
```

The share collection contains the shared listId and the user that has created this list and can be read without restrictions.

My problem is that I didn't know how to restrict the read operation on the users/items collection so that not any item can be retrieved but only the items on lists that are shared.

Comment: It's unfortunately hard to help with "Can't get my head arounds this". Without knowing specifically what single use-case you're having a hard time securing, it's unlikely we can do a better job explaining it than the documentation. Please edit your question to include the code that you've written for that use-case, explain how you expect these rules to function with that code, and how you've observed it functioning instead.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance @FrankvanPuffelen, edited my post to explain better where my problem is, hope that it's clearer now.

Comment: Did you try anything to write the `list` rule yet? If not, this would be a good place to start on securing access based on information from another document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#data-defined_attributes_and_roles. I'm not sure this is possible, due to the fact that rules are not filters on their own: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters.  But you'll know better after trying it, based on that documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your links @FrankvanPuffelen but don't think I can apply data-defined attributes here. Can't find this in the docs but is it maybe possible to access the query parameters or check for their existence in a rule a la:
allow list: if [the listId in my query] != null 

It would allow to see the items of a specific lists if you know the listId prevent to list all items of that user.